# making page scroll top with href="#"

Tags: html

At the bottom of my scrollable page I got a button "back to top" and I am unsure about just using `href="#"` for doing that job. I know about some functions/scripts solving the same too, but I am very attracted to that very easy way.

So my question is: What are the concrete disadvantages or dangers of using `href="#"` if it's about the scrolltotop-job?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/which-href-value-should-i-use-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0?rq=1

Comment: Your button will only work once unless the user interacts with another anchor in the interim.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/which-href-value-should-i-use-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

Comment: what about this? https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001475.htm

Comment: You can safe use href="#" but it will jump to top without any animation.
Animations is main purpose that these scripts are used.

Comment: ah good to know! the button just working once is not nice of course.. animations I dont need so far..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor tag is used for navigation inside a page. If you leave this empty the normal behaviour will be to scroll to the top of the page. You are litterly linking to a dead end and this is a bad behaviour. I would recommend adding a vissualy hidden span on top of your page and giving this div an ID. This way you can refer to this ID in your href. With a `scroll-behavior: smooth` property you can add a really smooth scroll function this way

Other solutions will be javascript.

```css
div{ height: 100vh; }
a { position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50vh; }
#upper{ position: absolute; top: 0; }
```

```html
<span id="upper"></span>
<div><h1>Title</h1></div>
<div><h1>Title</h1></div>
<div><h1>Title</h1></div>
<div><h1>Title</h1></div>
<div><h1>Title</h1></div>
<a href="#upper">Back to top</a>
```

Comment: good answer, thanks. But this anchor is also just working once, right? (unless there is no other anchor used after)

Comment: An anchor navigation will be set once but can be used mutliple times. So that won't be a problem